# gem "websocket-rails" and its scalability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket-rails

we are currently developing a chat (like facebook, with stored messages).
at the moment, theres a minimum of 500 online users (its a dating website) and at the peak there is a max of 3000 users simultanously online.

switching to websockets is "the thing" for us, but while using the gem "websocket-rails" we fear a little the performance.reading articles like https://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/ is causing some doubts.

so our question is:

does websocket-rails is killing our application or not? the other choice would be running a jsnode server and switch to faye which shouldnt be a problem in our scalabitliy. does somebody is having any expereince with the scalability of websocket-rails?

Comment: It might be a little tedious, but it might be best if you create a small simulation in which you have a few VMs/clients smashing your server with 3000 + concurrent connections while measuring the real-world server load. Articles like the one you posted do point out one of rails' big weaknesses--blocking io--but you might find that your servers will survive fine. Having a simulation script might also allow you to measure the "breaking point" on your rails system, which might be significantly above your expected customer throughput

Comment: can you give me any input where i can read more about how to create such a simulation? never did before :(

Answer (score 0):

The GIL is still here, but should not be the main issue. The main problem is that the Rails approach does not fit well in a massive chat approach.

My suggestion is to switch to event machine for this specific part, and still use websocket (or others push mechanism, like pusher), and use this kind of [WebSocket EventMachine Client](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-eventmachine-client).

You will be then event driven, with a single ruby thread and you still can use all the others rails existing libraries (that's the node.js model)

Comment: we wont use external stuff, we want to save that money. so you recommend to have a try with an own node.js server?

Comment: node, I recommend you to use EventMachine, which is a ruby event based approach + a websocket connection (you can do it by yourself ). It's the best approach in my opinion to do a chat in a rails based environment .